# NodeJS Passport Authentication - always redirected to failure url

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, passport-local

I am always redirected to the failure url irrespective of the login details, nothing is logged on the console and it is showing no errors. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Login Jade

```
extends layout

block content
  h1 Login
  p Please Login below
  form(method='post', action='/users/login',enctype='multipart/form-data')
    .form-group
      label Username
      input.form-control(name='username', type='text', placeholder='Enter username')
    .form-group
      label Password
      input.form-control(name='password', type='password', placeholder='Enter Password')
    input.btn.btn-default(name='submit', type='submit', value='Login')
```

User.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var multer = require('multer');
var uploads =  multer({ dest: './uploads' });
var passport = require('passport');
var localStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var User = require('../models/userModel');

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

router.get('/register', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('register',{ title: 'Register'})
});

router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('login',{ title: 'Login'})
});

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.getUserById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

passport.use(new localStrategy(
  function(username, password, done){
    User.getUserByUsername(username, function(err, user){
      if(err) throw err;
      if(!user){
        console.log('Unknown user');
        return done(null, false,{message:'Unkown User'});
      }
      User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
        if(err) throw err;
        if(isMatch){ return done(null, user)}
        else{
          console.log('Invalid password');
          return done(null, false,  {message:'Invalid Password'});
        }
      });
    });
  }
));


router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local',{failureRedirect:'/users/login',failureFlash: true }), function(req, res){
  console.log('Auth Sucessful');
  req.flash('sucess','Logged in');
  res.redirect('/');
});


module.exports = router;
```

And my UserModel.js it has comparePassword and getUserByUsername.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/nodeauth');
var db = mongoose.connection;

//Schema
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username:{
    type:String,
    index:true
  },
  password:{
    type:String,
    bcrypt :true,
    required: true
  },
  email:String,

  name:String,

  profileImage:{
    type:String
  }
}); 


var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User',UserSchema);

module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash , callback){
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, ismatch){
    if(err) return callback(err);
    callback(null, ismatch);
  });
}

module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback){
  var query = {username : username};
  User.findOne(query, function(err, user) {
    callback(err, user);
  }); 
}

module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
  User.findById(id,callback);
}

module.exports.createUser = function(newUser,callback){
  bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, 10, function(err, hash){
    if(err) throw err;
    //Set hash password
    newUser.password = hash;
    newUser.save(callback);
  } );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  function(username, password, done){

    User.getUserByUsername(username, function(err, user){
      if(err) throw err;
      if(!user){
        console.log('Unknown user');
        return done(null, false,{message:'Unkown User'});
      }

      User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
        if(err) throw err;
        if(isMatch){ return done(null, user)}
        else{
          console.log('Invalid password');
          return done(null, false,  {message:'Invalid Password'});
        }

      });
    });

  }
```

This is where your problem should occur. Since `if(err) throw err;`
 is present and you're not getting errors, it is very likely that whatever happens is not considered an error, so it must be your logic that fails at a point.

You should test, whether your passwords return properly, or if the bcrypt comparation in UserModel works as it should. These are the main points I can see critical for now.